# Retrieve data from JSON with PHP

Tags: php, html, json

I am trying to retrieve the values from json file from this link: http://api.edmunds.com/api/vehicle/v2/vins/WAUYP54B01N099265?fmt=json&api_key=2jwwaax2sc4kuq7vg7ud79rc I am trying to do this with PHP but for some reason it isn't working.

Here is my current code:

```
<?php
// copy file content into a string var
$json_file = file_get_contents('http://api.edmunds.com/api/vehicle/v2/vins/WAUYP54B01N099265?fmt=json&api_key=2jwwaax2sc4kuq7vg7ud79rc');
// convert the string to a json object
$jfo = json_decode($json_file);
// read the title value
$title = $jfo->make->name;
// copy the posts array to a php var
$posts = $jfo->make->id;
// listing posts
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo $post->title;
}
?>

<ul class="ul_json clearfix">
<?php
foreach ($posts as $post) {
?>
<li>
<a href="<?php echo $post->link; ?>">
<h2><?php echo $post->title; ?></h2>

</a>
</li>
<?php
} // end foreach
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: `$jfo->make->id` is an integer (and not an object/array) so you can't loop over it.

Comment: Can you rewrite code for me please?

Comment: What part of the code doesn't work, does `$title = $jfo->make->name;` get's its name..

Comment: And there's much mistakes, as i can see there's no `title`, `link` in file as key ?

Comment: It seems you are right, loop was the problem. After i have simply echoed posts and title var it printed out values i need. Thanks again, users of sof!

Comment: I still have the problem getting the year from this JSON. How can i find out which element is the parent of year attribute?